# How do I filter products based on category using jquery given that they are on two separate json files?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, this is a little tricky on my side. I have two json files, food.json and rest_category.json. I am trying to find a way to filter the foods in food.json based on the category in rest_category.json. I got an idea that perhaps I should add a foreign_id in food.json that matches the id in category in rest_category.json. Still, how do I proceed from there? Is there a way that I could attempt this? I'd really appreciate it. Thanks
Below is a sample of my food.json and rest_category.json. 
food.json

```
[

{
    "id":"1",
    "Name":"Coke 500ml",
    "Price":"80",
    "Quantity": "50",
    "Category":"Beverages"
},

{
    "id":"2",
    "Name":"Cake",
    "Price":"150",
    "Quantity": "40",
    "Category":"Appetizer"
},

{
    "id":"3",
    "Name":"Beef Ribs",
    "Price":"100",
    "Quantity": "50",
    "Category":"Side Items"
},

{
    "id":"4",
    "Name":"Cabbage Salad",
    "Price":"50",
    "Quantity": "30",
    "Category":"Salads"
},

{
    "id":"5",
    "Name":"Cake",
    "Price":"150",        
    "Quantity": "30",
    "Category":"Appetizer"
},

{
    "id":"6",
    "Name":"Beef Ribs",
    "Price":"100",
    "Quantity": "30",
    "Category":"Side Items"
}
]
```

rest_category.json

```
[
{
    "id" : "1",
    "name" : "Appetizers",
    "Status" : "Active"   
},

{
    "id" : "2",
    "name" : "Salads",
    "Status" : "Active"         
},

{
    "id" : "3",
    "name" : "Entrees",
    "Status" : "Active"    
},

{
    "id" : "4",
    "name" : "Side Items",
    "Status" : "Active"    
},

{
    "id" : "5",
    "name" : "Beverages",
    "Status" : "Active" 
}
]
```

Just to add, the response should be displayed on a HTML page. I am currently able to append a list of categories and foods. Stuck on the filter section. 
Below is my sample code I used to append the categories and food.

// display products from json file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.getJSON("../json/food.json", function(data) {
    var food_data = '';
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        food_data += '<div id = "product_sect" class = "product">'
        food_data += '<a href = "#"> <img class = "food-image" src = 
"../images/dinner.svg"></a>'
        food_data += '<p style = "margin:0;" id = "FoodName">' + 
value.Name + '<p class = "p_quantity" id = FoodQuantity>' + 'Qty:' + 
value.Quantity + '</p>' + '<p class = "p_price" id = "FoodPrice">' +  
value.Price + "/=" + '</p>' + '</p>'
        food_data += '<a id = "cart-click" class = "btn btn-primary add- 
        to-cart" href = "#" data-id= + "'+value.ID+'">Add to Cart</i></a>'
        food_data += '</div>'

    });
    $('#product_grid').append(food_data)
});
```

});

//display categories from json file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.getJSON("../json/rest_category.json", function(data) {
    var cat_data = '';
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        cat_data += '<a href = "#">' + value.name + '</a>'
    });
    $('#rest_category').append(cat_data)
});
});
```

Comment: whta is the sample of the response you are expecting

Comment: It should be displayed on a page. I am currently able to display the food and category, but unable to perform the filter.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a try to [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```js
const arr = [

  {
    "id": "1",
    "Name": "Coke 500ml",
    "Price": "80",
    "Quantity": "50",
    "Category": "Beverages"
  },

  {
    "id": "2",
    "Name": "Cake",
    "Price": "150",
    "Quantity": "40",
    "Category": "Appetizer"
  },

  {
    "id": "3",
    "Name": "Beef Ribs",
    "Price": "100",
    "Quantity": "50",
    "Category": "Side Items"
  },

  {
    "id": "4",
    "Name": "Cabbage Salad",
    "Price": "50",
    "Quantity": "30",
    "Category": "Salads"
  },

  {
    "id": "5",
    "Name": "Cake",
    "Price": "150",
    "Quantity": "30",
    "Category": "Appetizer"
  },

  {
    "id": "6",
    "Name": "Beef Ribs",
    "Price": "100",
    "Quantity": "30",
    "Category": "Side Items"
  }
];

function filterArrayByCategory(category) {
  return arr.filter(el => el.Category === category);
}

console.log(filterArrayByCategory('Appetizer'));
```

Comment: It works perfectly.  but this is my problem..Instead of specifying the category in the javascript file as so **console.log(filterArrayByCategory('Appetizer'));** I need it to be like, when I click on a category on a page, it displays food associated with that category.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Array.map` and `Array.filter`:

```js
let products = [

{
    "id":"1",
    "Name":"Coke 500ml",
    "Price":"80",
    "Quantity": "50",
    "Category":"Beverages"
},

{
    "id":"2",
    "Name":"Cake",
    "Price":"150",
    "Quantity": "40",
    "Category":"Appetizer"
},

{
    "id":"3",
    "Name":"Beef Ribs",
    "Price":"100",
    "Quantity": "50",
    "Category":"Side Items"
},

{
    "id":"4",
    "Name":"Cabbage Salad",
    "Price":"50",
    "Quantity": "30",
    "Category":"Salads"
},

{
    "id":"5",
    "Name":"Cake",
    "Price":"150",        
    "Quantity": "30",
    "Category":"Appetizer"
},

{
    "id":"6",
    "Name":"Beef Ribs",
    "Price":"100",
    "Quantity": "30",
    "Category":"Side Items"
}
];

let categories = [
{
    "id" : "1",
    "name" : "Appetizers",
    "Status" : "Active"   
},

{
    "id" : "2",
    "name" : "Salads",
    "Status" : "Active"         
},

{
    "id" : "3",
    "name" : "Entrees",
    "Status" : "Active"    
},

{
    "id" : "4",
    "name" : "Side Items",
    "Status" : "Active"    
},

{
    "id" : "5",
    "name" : "Beverages",
    "Status" : "Active" 
}
];

let result = categories.map(c=>{
  return {
    ...c,
    products : products.filter(p=>p.Category===c.name)
  }
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(result,null,2));
```

Comment: Now, you can show your category/products in tree way.

Answer (score 0):

In order to help you to achieve your goals I'm going to add another answer, which will show you another approach. Please use it as a reference and adapt to your code based on your current implementation:

```js
const hardCodedFood = [

  {
    "id": "1",
    "Name": "Coke 500ml",
    "Price": "80",
    "Quantity": "50",
    "Category": "Beverages"
  },

  {
    "id": "2",
    "Name": "Cake",
    "Price": "150",
    "Quantity": "40",
    "Category": "Appetizer"
  },

  {
    "id": "3",
    "Name": "Beef Ribs",
    "Price": "100",
    "Quantity": "50",
    "Category": "Side Items"
  },

  {
    "id": "4",
    "Name": "Cabbage Salad",
    "Price": "50",
    "Quantity": "30",
    "Category": "Salads"
  },

  {
    "id": "5",
    "Name": "Cake",
    "Price": "150",
    "Quantity": "30",
    "Category": "Appetizer"
  },

  {
    "id": "6",
    "Name": "Beef Ribs",
    "Price": "100",
    "Quantity": "30",
    "Category": "Side Items"
  }
];

const $categories = $('#categories');
const $availableFoodByCategory = $('#availableFoodByCategory');

hardCodedFood.forEach(el => {
  let $option = $('<option/>', {
    value: el.Category,
    text: el.Category
  });

  $option.appendTo($categories)
});

$categories.on('change', function() {
  $availableFoodByCategory.empty();
  hardCodedFood
    .filter(el => el.Category === $(this).val()) // filtering dynamically based on category provided
    .forEach(el => {
      let $row = $('<tr/>');
      $('<td/>', {
        text: el.id
      }).appendTo($row);
      $('<td/>', {
        text: el.Name
      }).appendTo($row);
      $('<td/>', {
        text: el.Price
      }).appendTo($row);
      $('<td/>', {
        text: el.Quantity
      }).appendTo($row);

      $row.appendTo(availableFoodByCategory);
    });

  $availableFoodByCategory.show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='categories'></select>

<table id='availableFoodByCategory' style='display:none;'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please consider approving my answer, if it really solves your problem and fits your expectations